# Change Specific Property of the State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS and needless to say I am an absolute beginner! I am trying to change a specific property in the array of objects which belongs to state. Every object has two properties: **name** and **active**. active values are false by default. **When I click on the item, I want to change this item's active value to true.**

My array is shown inside of the list element and every list element has `onClick={() => props.onChangeSelected(lang.name)}` method. `onChangeSleceted` method goes to `handleChangeSelected(name)` function, however, I couldn't figure out what to write inside of this function.

```
  class Loading extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          text: 'Loading'
        };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        const stopper = this.state.text + '...';

        this.interval = window.setInterval(() => {
          this.state.text === stopper
            ? this.setState(() => ({ text: 'Loading' }))
            : this.setState((prevState) => ({ text: prevState.text + '.' }))
        }, 300)
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        window.clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <p>
            {this.state.text}
          </p>
        )
      }
    }

    function LanguageList (props) {
      return (
          <div>
          <h3>Choose your favorite:</h3>
          <ul>
          {props.list.map((lang) => (
            <li key={lang.name} onClick={() => props.onChangeSelected(lang.name)}>
            <span>{lang.name}</span>
            </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          </div>
        )
    }

 class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          languages: [
            {
              name: 'all',
              active: true
            },

            {
              name: 'javascript',
              active: false
            },

            {
              name: 'ruby',
              active: false
            },
            {
              name: 'python',
              active: false
            }

          ]
        }

        this.handleChangeSelected = this.handleChangeSelected.bind(this)
      }

      handleChangeSelected(name) {
         this.setState((currentState) => {
             const lang = currentState.languages.find((lang) => lang.name === name)
             return {}
         })
      }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <LanguageList 
            list={this.state.languages}
            onChangeSelected={this.handleChangeSelected}
            />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById('app')
    )
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a number of ways. All you need to make sure is that you aren't mutating the original state array

```
  handleChangeSelected(name) {
     this.setState((currentState) => {
         return { languages: currentState.languages.map((lang) => {
              if(lang.name === name) {
                   return {...lang, active: true};
              }
              return lang;
         });
     })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
handleChangeSelected(name){

    // Find matching element in state
    var temp = this.state.languages;

    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
        if (temp[i]["name"] === name){
            temp[i]["active"] = true;
        }
    }

    this.setState({
        languages: temp
    });
}
```

As listed in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), they recommend creating a new object when calling the `setState` function. This is of course talking about the updater function syntax (`this.setState((prevState, props) => {return {...};});`), which I assume the same logic is applied to the syntax used above (passing an object into set state)

> The first argument [to setState] is an updater function with the signature:
>
> `(prevState, props) => stateChange`
>
> (prevState, props) => stateChange prevState is a reference to the
>   previous state. **It should not be directly mutated**. Instead, changes
>   should be represented by building a new object based on the input from
>   prevState and props.

Comment: It should work, however I am trying to find a different solution. I mean it must be a way to use functional programming for that.

Comment: Updated my answer. The react docs say you should be passing into a new object into the `setState` method. I assume this reasoning is behind all of the different ways you can set objects on the state as listed in their docs (including the method in my answer above): https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate